# Push_back elements dissapear after function is finished

Tags: c++

I'm trying to recursively iterate through a tree of nodes and extract the bone structure by pushing elements to a vector called children using push_back() function. I can clearly see that the elements are being added but after the iteration is completed all children from the 2nd generation and below disappear.

```
struct Bone
{
    int id = 0;
    std::string name = "";
    glm::mat4 offset = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 globalTransform = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    std::vector<Bone> children = {};
};

void readSkeletonRec(Bone& parent, aiNode* node, glm::mat4 parentNodeTransform)
    {
        glm::mat4 globalTransform = parentNodeTransform * assimpToGlmMatrix(node->mTransformation);
        if (boneInfoTable.find(node->mName.C_Str()) != boneInfoTable.end())
        {
            countBones++;
            Bone child;
            child.name = node->mName.data;
            child.id = boneInfoTable[child.name].first;
            child.offset = boneInfoTable[child.name].second;
            child.globalTransform = globalTransform;
            printf("ADDING: To %s, child: %s\n", parent.name.c_str(), child.name.c_str());
            parent.children.push_back(child);
            for (int i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
            {
                readSkeletonRec(child, node->mChildren[i], globalTransform);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
            {
                readSkeletonRec(parent, node->mChildren[i], globalTransform);
            }
        }
    }
```

Below we can see that they have indeed been added.

[image]

And yet when I iterated through the tree they disappeared.

[image]

I've been trying to figure it out for some time now and couldn't find any clues on the web. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing disappeared from the bone in `parent.children` - it was just never modified.

`push_back` adds a *copy* of `Bone child` to `parent.children`. That means you now have two bones: the original one still referred to by `child`, and the  one in `parent.children`.

You pass the original bone to the recursive call. That recursive call adds more stuff to the bone that it gets - but not to the copy that was added to `parent.children`.

There are a few possible approaches to fixing this, but I think a reasonable one would be to not have two copies, but only store bones in `parent.children`, like so (untested):

```
            Bone &child = parent.children.emplace_back();
            child.name = node->mName.data;
            ...
            for (int i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
            {
                readSkeletonRec(child, node->mChildren[i], globalTransform);
            }
```

Comment: Riiiight. Makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As you know, `std::vector` can be reallocated when the vector size increase.

The problem is here, I add snippet of that.

```cpp
            ...
            Bone child;
            ...
            parent.children.push_back(child);
            ...
            {
            ...
                readSkeletonRec(child, node->mChildren[i], globalTransform);
            ...
            }
```

You pushed `child` to `parent.children` (here it is copied - not moved)
After that you passed `child` to `readSkeletonRec()` (after function finished the change of `child` is not applyed to `parent.children`.

Try use `readSkeletonRec(parent.children[parent.children.size()-1], node->mChildren[i], globalTransform);`